# How to include content-range header to an http request from Logic app?

Tags: rest, azure-logic-apps, http-content-range

I have a system url Endpoint which requires the user to send some mandatory information in the header part, One of which is Content-range in the following format:

"Content-Range": "bytes 0-4/5"; (start range-end range/total size)

I am trying to call the url from logic app using the HTTP action.
However this returns 500 Internal server error. On further debugging I understand that Microsoft logic app  removes the "Content-Range" header from the generated request message without showing any warning or error. Is there any workaround to avoid the header from being ignored? Thanks.

Comment: does this help? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-handle-large-messages

Comment: Hi @codebrane I did come across this document, However my requirement is irrespective of the message/file size.

Answer (score 0):

you can mentioned in header section of http like below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFBOi.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).